# recreate scale_fill_brewer with scale_fill_manual

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to understand the connection between `scale_fill_brewer` and `scale_fill_manual` of package `ggplot2`.

First, generate a ggplot with filled colors:

```
library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = wt, 
    group = cyl, fill = factor(cyl))) + 
    geom_area(position = 'stack')

# apply ready-made palette with scale_fill_brewer from ggplot2
p + scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Blues")
```

[image]

Now, replicate with `scale_fill_manual`

```
library(RColorBrewer)
p + scale_fill_manual(values = brewer.pal(3, "Blues"))
```

where 3 is the number of fill-colors in the data. For convenience, I have used the `brewer.pal` function of package `RColorBrewer`.

As far as I understand, the convenience of `scale_fill_brewer` is that it automatically computes the number of unique levels in the data (3 in this example). Here is my attempt at replicating:

```
p + scale_fill_manual(values = brewer.pal(length(levels(factor(mtcars$cyl))), "Blues"))
```

**My question is: how does `scale_fill_brewer` compute the number of levels in the data?**

I'm interested in understanding what else `fill_color_brewer` might be doing under the hood. Might I run into any difficulty if I replace the more user friendly `fill_color_brewer` with a more contorted implementation of `scale_fill_manual` like the one above.

Perusing the source code:

```
scale_fill_brewer
function (..., type = "seq", palette = 1) {
    discrete_scale("fill", "brewer", brewer_pal(type, palette), ...)
}
```

I couldn't see through this how `scale_fill_brewer` computes the number of unique levels in the data. Perhaps hidden in the `...` ?

**Edit: Where does the function `scale_fill_brewer` receive instructions to compute the number of levels in the data? Is it in `"seq"` or in `...` or elsewhere?**

The `discrete_scale` function is intricate and I'm lost. Here are its arguments:

```
discrete_scale <- function(aesthetics, scale_name, palette, name = NULL, 
    breaks = waiver(), labels = waiver(), legend = NULL, limits = NULL, 
    expand = waiver(), na.value = NA, drop = TRUE, guide="legend") {
```

Does any of this compute the number of levels?

Comment: I find ggplot2's source code kind of intricate, but you can start there: https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/blob/master/R/scale-brewer.r

Comment: Thanks Roland, that's where one finds ``scale_fill_brewer`` (copied in my question), but the mystery to me is how ``..., type = "seq"`` makes the function count the number of levels (if that's what's going on).

Comment: The next step is obviously to look up the definition of `discrete_scale`. Or is your question how the ellipses work in R? That has been explained numerous times on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Thanks Roland. My question is how when you use ``scale_fill_brewer``, as in the example above, the number of levels in the data is automatically computed: where does this come from? who does the work? Is it in the ``...`` somehow or in the ``seq``? How does ``scale_fill_brewer`` know where to look for levels and how to count? is that something ``discrete_scale`` does? EDITED the question to clarify, hopefully.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way is to trace it is to think in terms of (1) setting up the plot data structure, and (2) *resolving* the aesthetics. It uses S3 so the branching is implicit

The setup call sequence

1. [scale-brewer.R] `scale_fill_brewer(type="seq", palette="Blues")`
2. [scale-.R] `discrete_scale(...)` - return an object representing the scale

```
  structure(list(
    call = match.call(),

    aesthetics = aesthetics,
    scale_name = scale_name,
    palette = palette,

    range = DiscreteRange$new(),        ## this is scales::DiscreteRange 
    ...), , class = c(scale_name, "discrete", "scale"))
```

The resolve call sequence

1. [plot-build.R] `ggplot_build(plot)` - for non-position scales, apply scales_train_df

```
    # Train and map non-position scales
    npscales <- scales$non_position_scales()       ## scales is plot$scales, S4 type Scales
    if (npscales$n() > 0) {
      lapply(data, scales_train_df, scales = npscales)
      data <- lapply(data, scales_map_df, scales = npscales)
    }
```

2. [scales-.r] `scales_train_df(...)` - iterate again over scales$scales (list)
3. [scale-.r] `scale_train_df(...)` - iterate again
4. [scale-.r] `scale_train(...)` - S3 generic function
5. [scale-.r] `scale_train.discrete(...)` - almost there...

```
    scale$range$train(x, drop = scale$drop)
```

6. but scale$range is a DiscreteRange instance, so it calls `(scales::DiscreteRange$new())$train`, which overwrites scale$range!

```
    range <<- train_discrete(x, range, drop)
```

7. `scales:::train_discrete(...)` - again, almost there...
8. `scales:::discrete_range(...)` - still not there..
9. `scales:::clevels(...)` - there it is!

As of this point, `scale$range` has been overwritten by the levels of the factor. Unwinding the call stack to #1, we now call scales_map_df

1. [plot-build.R] `ggplot_build(plot)` - for non-position scales, apply scales_train_df

```
    # Train and map non-position scales
    npscales <- scales$non_position_scales()       ## scales is plot$scales, S4 type Scales
    if (npscales$n() > 0) {
      lapply(data, scales_train_df, scales = npscales)
      data <- lapply(data, scales_map_df, scales = npscales)
    }
```

2. [scales-.r] `scale_maps_df(...)` - iterate
3. [scale-.r] `scale_map_df(...)` - iterate
4. [scale-.r] `scale_map.discrete` - fill up the palette (non-position scale!)

   scale_map.discrete <- function(scale, x, limits = scale_limits(scale)) {
     n <- sum(!is.na(limits))
     pal <- scale$palette(n)
     ...
   }